Live Preview while customizing is not showing the updates while editing in WordPress
I'm working on a small website in WordPress, when clicking the "customize" button, it will open a page that shows a "Live Preview" of the website and allows you to add custom CSS to the website. While adding CSS properties, the changes are shown directly in the Live Preview. These changes are not shown in the real website until clicking the "Publish" button. So, the idea is that the Live Preview is not showing me the changes while adding CSS properties. Can someone till me how to solve it? Thanks in advance.
